# Is it possible for a vanishing entire function to have constant modulus "for a while"?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, entire-functions

I am wondering if it is possible for an entire function $\phi$ to admit a direction $v\in\Bbb C$ such that $\phi(tv)\to0$ for $t\to+\infty$ but $|\phi|$ is constant "for a while" in that direction, that is, there exists an interval $[t_1v,t_2v]$, where $t_1<t_2$, in which $|\phi|$ is constant.

I am trying to find such an example but nothing comes in mind. I still don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible. Without loss of generality I'll take $v=1$ (otherwise consider $z \mapsto \phi(v z)$ instead). If $\lvert \phi \rvert=1$ on some real interval then $\overline{\phi(\overline{z})} = \phi(z)^{-1}$ on that interval and since both sides are holomorphic equality holds throughout $\mathbb{C}$. In particular for all $z\in \mathbb{R}$: $\overline{\phi(z)} = \phi(z)^{-1}$, that is, $\lvert \phi(z) \rvert=1$.

Comment: Why do we need the conjugate of $z$ above? I think you could use just $|\phi(z)|^2=\overline{\phi(z)}\phi(z)$

Comment: $\overline{\phi(z)}$ is not a holomorphic function in general but $\overline{\phi(\overline{z})}$ is. You need that to extend equality from the interval to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: And how can we get the equality $\overline{\phi(\bar{z})}=\phi(z)^{-1}$?

Comment: For $z\in\mathbb{R}$ That's just stating that $\lvert \phi(z) \rvert^2 = 1$.

Comment: But the argument extend to $v\neq1$, right? I think we can apply a rotation, execute your argument and rotate it back, isn't it?

Comment: To the proposer:  If  there was an example for $\phi$ with $v\ne 1$ then $\psi(z)=\phi (vz)$  would be an example with $v=1.$ So we only need to show no such $\psi$ exists.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet WimC added that to his answer yesterday...